# MediaWiki NavFrame snippet not working in 1.15

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

Using 1.15.0 mediawiki, and a custom skin, for some reason, the common.js fails to create actual navframes.

reference: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Collapsible_elements#NavFrame

I copied both the common.css and the common.js from this page, as is, and while the common.js loads(tried with an *`alert("test loading of common.js");`*) it does not make a navframe.

I also tried switching to both standard and monobook skins, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script uses a bit of jQuery, but there is [no jQuery in MediaWiki 1.15](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/JQuery). It was introduced in 1.16.

You can try maybe with an older version of that script, such as [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MediaWiki%3aCommon.js&oldid=381139023) - apparently jQuery-free - which dates from when MediaWiki 1.15 was still used at Wikipedia.